# Is there a Siri command for "Get directions to my next event?"

Tags: calendar, siri

I can say to Siri "Get directions to the nearest post office" and it will pull it up. However, sometimes I am on my way to an event that is in my calendar with the address. I would like to say "Get directions to my next event". However, that doesn't work as it pulls up event centers instead.

Is there some other phrasing I can say to express what I want to Siri?

Comment: This is why I hate Siri. Apple has fallen really far behind Google and even Amazon in this area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is impossible to do as of iOS 10.3.3. About the closest thing you can do is, `"Hey Siri where is my next appointment"`, but there is no way to get directions from the address it spits out.

What I'd recommend, instead of using Siri, is to create a widget in [Workflow](https://workflow.is/) that will automatically grab the next event's location and give you directions. *Note: I have never used Workflow to do this myself but I'm 99% sure it has all the various actions you would need to write a workflow to give you directions with one click.*

Sorry you are unable to use Siri in this way and hopefully Workflow will accomplish what you're looking to do.

Comment: This is a great idea, and since I recently downloaded Workflow from Apple, I had a look. They provide several examples, one of which is "Directions to Next Event". I edited it so that it's "today" and limited to one event. Then, you add the workflow to the home screen, and as Jalen said, "one click to get the directions." Can't seem to open it with Siri, though.

Comment: No I don't think it will work with Siri. But at least for now it's faster than opening calendar, clicking the event, clicking the address, and then getting directions. You can also add it as a widget so you can access it from the lockscreen if you don't want to have to unlock the phone to access it.

Comment: Nice thinking Jalen. :) Since I already use Workflow I decided to experiment with this a little.  You can actually use Siri, but only in a limited way at this stage. I edited the *Directions to Next Event* workflow in a similar way to how @Zonker.in.Geneva did. Then to use it with Siri you can tap on the *Directions to Next Event* workflow button within the Workflow app and say "Hey Siri, remind me about this" (or, if you don't use 'Hey Siri', invoke it by holding down the Home button). Siri then adds it to your reminders, but then you have to *manually* set it to alert you.

Comment: When it does, tapping on the alert gives you the option to Open Workflow. When you do you get prompted about your next event and tapping on it will open Maps and off you go. Of course this is all a bit *limited*, but I know that Apple is doing a lot of work with both Siri and Workflow, so hopefully we'll see some dramatic improvements on this front soon. :)

Comment: It’s been 6 years… has this been fixed yet?